# Joins of (closed) subschemes and Zariski-local Z-functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes

$\newcommand\Aff{\mathrm{Aff}}\newcommand\cRing{\mathrm{cRing}}\newcommand\Sch{\mathrm{Sch}}$Equip $\Aff = \cRing^\text{op}$ with the Zariski Grothendieck-topology. There are nested categories:
$$\Aff\hookrightarrow \Sch\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Sh}(\Aff) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Pr}(\Aff).$$
Fix a (functorial) scheme $X$. The scheme has preorders of closed subschemes, schemes and Zariski-local subfunctors in increasing order. How do the lattice operations (if they exist) compare?

- Is the preorder of subschemes of $X$ a lattice? Does a join $S\vee_{\Sch}T$ of two subschemes exist?
- If yes, does it agree with $S\vee_{\operatorname{Sh}(\Aff)}T$?
- If $S$ and $T $ are closed subschemes, then there is a join in the lattice of closed subschemes. Do any of the equations $S\vee_\text{closed}T=S\vee_{\Sch}T=S\vee_{\operatorname{Sh}(\Aff)}T$ hold?

Example: We have that $V(x) \vee_\text{closed}V(y) =V(xy)$ in $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[x,y]$, but this doesn't seem to be the same as $V(x)\vee_{\operatorname{Sh}(\Aff)}V(y)$, for if it were then $$\operatorname{Sh}(\Aff)\models\forall x:\mathbb A_\mathbb Z.\forall y:\mathbb A_\mathbb Z. \quad xy=0 \leftrightarrow (x=0 \vee y=0)$$
would be true in the internal language, but it isn't.

Comment: I must have read the title 5 times before it occurred to me that the reason I was having so much trouble was that there were two "of"s.  Edited accordingly.